# Editors cannot edit certain aspects of presentation details, such as a component's datasource or placeholder

Tags: presentation, security, placeholders, datasource

I am working on an issue facing some Sitecore editors.

These editors can edit items normally once it is locked to them but cannot edit certain aspects of presentation details of those items.  If the presentation details of those items are exposed using the device editor, they are unable to updated datasource reference on any of the components or update the placeholder being used by that component.

I am trying to figure out if there are a set of items in the master or core database which I can target and override for their accounts so they can perform this activity on those items.

Does anyone knows which items those are ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to assign the following roles to these users:

- Sitecore\Designer

> Gives the user read and write access to the areas of the content tree
>   that are required when changing layout details for individual items
>   and groups of items via template standard values, as well as items
>   required when configuring the Experience Editor Design Pane.
>
> This role also has two of the Sitecore Client roles assigned to it, so
>   if you assign just this role to a user, the Sitecore Client Designing
>   and Sitecore Client Users roles will be automatically assigned to the
>   user.
>
> This role provides access to the Experience Editor Design Pane
>   features and the designer options in the Content Editor.

- Sitecore\Author

> Gives the user access to content in the content tree. This role
>   provides access to basic item editing features, such as the Media
>   Library and the Content Editor, with a reduced set of tabs on the
>   ribbon.
>
> This role also has two of the Sitecore Client roles as members, so if
>   you assign just this role to a user, the Sitecore Client Authoring and
>   Sitecore Client Users roles will be automatically assigned to the
>   user.

Reference: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/the-security-roles.html